# JavaScript- Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hey guys i'm developing a tracking system in which i have to use the API of google maps to calculate ETA (estimated time of arrival).
I have the driving distance.
But I need the kilometers away to the arrival point in order to be able to predict the time of arrival.

How do I call the driving distance value below?

```
directionsService.route(request, 
function(response, status) {
     if ( status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK ) {
            (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value); // the distance in metres
                return((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value)/1000); //distance e kilometres
                 }
                  else {
                    // oops, there's no route between these two locations
                    // every time this happens, a kitten dies
                    // so please, ensure your address is formatted properly
                }
            });


function getArrivalTime(distance, vel) {
        return distance / vel;
    };
    console.log(getArrivalTime(distance,vel));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually put your directions request in your function, getArrivalTime. Then you could simply create a var to hold the distance and set it equal to response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value)/1000 Please see code sample here:

```
function getArrivalTime(vel) {
    var distance;
    directionsService.route(request, 
    function(response, status) {
    if ( status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK ) {
        (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value); // the distance in metres
            distance = ((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value)/1000); //distance e kilometres
             }
              else {
                // oops, there's no route between these two locations
                // every time this happens, a kitten dies
                // so please, ensure your address is formatted properly
            }
        });
    return distance / vel;
};
console.log(getArrivalTime(distance,vel));
```

You may need to put a timeout around return(distance,vel) to ensure the API call has had time to respond to the request before you return the data. One other option would be to create a global variable to hold distance so that you can access it in any function. It's typically best to avoid global variables though, so I'd recommend the first way I mentioned.

I hope this helps!